# Type 'AbstractControl | null' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have problem passing `[formGroup]` to children components in Angular. It says `Type 'AbstractControl | null' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup'`. I think i have put all safe conditions and I have initialize it well. I don't understand why is this still happening. The error is on this `[formGroup]="linkAccounts?.get('bank')"` in `link-accounts.component.html`

**register.component.ts**

```js
linkAccountsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  bank: this.formBuilder.group({
    bank_name: [null, Validators.required],
    account_name: [null, Validators.required],
    account_number: [null, Validators.required],
    swift_code: [null, Validators.required],
  }),
  credit_card: this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [null, Validators.required],
    card_number: [null, Validators.required],
    cvc: [null, Validators.required],
    exp_date: [null, Validators.required],
  }),
});
```

**register.component.html**

```html
<form
  [formGroup]="linkAccountsForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onLinkAccount(linkAccountsForm)"
>
  <app-link-accounts
    [linkAccounts]="linkAccountsForm"
    [step]="step"
    [submitted]="submitted"
  ></app-link-accounts>
</form>
```

**link-accounts.component.ts**

```js
 @Input() linkAccounts!: FormGroup;
 @Input() step!: number;
 @Input() submitted!: boolean;
```

**link-accounts.component.html**

```html
<div [formGroup]="linkAccounts" *ngIf="step === 2">
  <app-bank
    [parentForm]="linkAccounts"
    [formGroup]="linkAccounts?.get('bank')"
  ></app-bank>
  <button type="submit" class="custom-login-button">Done</button>
</div>
```

**bank.component.ts**

```js
public bank!: FormGroup;
@Input() parentForm!: FormGroup;

constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {}

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.bank = this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;

  console.log(this.logForms)
}

public logForms(): void {
  console.log('Hobbies form', this.bank);
  console.log('Parent (Hero) form', this.parentForm);
}
```

Comment: Could you show also `bank.component.html` and also more context about the error message ? Does it give you the component that issued the error message ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle. I have not put anything in `bank.component.html`. The error is on this `[formGroup]="linkAccounts?.get('bank')"` in `link-accounts.component.html`

Comment: You don't have any `@Input() formGroup` in `bank.component.ts` so `[formGroup]="linkAccounts?.get('bank')"` does not seem valid in `link-accounts.component.html`. I would not expect this error message though

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle the values from `bank.component.ts` comes from `link` and `link` comes from `register`. the whole form is initialize in the `register`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to cast the `linkAccounts?.get('bank')` to a `FormGroup` to be assignable to the `formGroup`, because the `type` of the form `controls` is `AbstractControl | null`.

**#1 Solution:** using a getter with `FormGroup` type:

```js
get bankFormGroup(): FormGroup {
  return this.linkAccountsForm?.get('bank') as FormGroup;
}
```

```html
<div [formGroup]="linkAccounts" *ngIf="step === 2">
  <app-bank [parentForm]="linkAccounts" [formGroup]="bankFormGroup"></app-bank>
  <button type="submit" class="custom-login-button">Done</button>
</div>
```

**#2 Solution:** using a `$any()` casting in the component template:

```html
<div [formGroup]="linkAccounts" *ngIf="step === 2">
  <app-bank
    [parentForm]="linkAccounts"
    [formGroup]="$any(linkAccounts?.get('bank'))"
  ></app-bank>
  <button type="submit" class="custom-login-button">Done</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Which better?  @Amer